How does Husserl differentiate mathematics from physics?
As I understand it, for Husserl, the objects of physics, while they can be idealized in some contexts, always retain a reference to something that can be experienced. For example, concepts such as mass, velocity, or force are grounded in experience and the physical world.
In contrast, in mathematics, mathematical objects are pure abstractions. They do not depend on time, space, or any physical conditions; rather, they are understood in terms of abstract relations and properties. Husserl places them in the "ideal domain," independent of empirical reality.
However, this does not seem sufficient to me, since both physics and mathematics originate from the lifeworld that we all perceive. I feel I might be overlooking something here.

Indeed the critical insight is from the empirical fact that they both originate from the same merged intersubjective lifeworld or worldlife landscape we share externally, in this sense, Husserl cannot differentiate one from the other based on their origin alone like twins, need to further identify based on their different developed properties once they grow naturally enough, a twin space...

@DoubleKnot OK, perfect, in their genesis they share the same soil. I understand that what differentiates them is what they both abstract. What would it be in the case of Husserl? In Aristotle it would be motion and quantity, respectively; and in Husserl?

A Husserlian transcendental ego from his Logical Investigation series might hint its indispensability to identify math...

@DoubleKnot May I ask how this answers my question?

This transcendental ego provides the stability needed to distinguish mathematical entities as pure idealities, not as mundane idealization, say, those of physics. While a specific physical experience may vary across individuals and contexts, a mathematical concept like "two" or "circle" is meant to be invariant and universal. Husserl saw this constancy not as an empirical accident but as something grounded in the intentional nature of consciousness itself, which he increasingly understood as transcendental ego, fully developed in his Ideas I,  10 years after his Logical Investigations...

@DoubleKnotYes, the Transcendental Ego explains the condition of possibility for mathematical statements, categorical judgements, abstractions, etc. But it does not explain what specific difference mathematics has from physics, unless I misunderstood you.

See Stefania Centrone (editor), Essays on Husserl's Logic and Philosophy of Mathematics (Springer, 2017), Ch.1 Husserl and Leibniz: Notes on the Mathesis
Universalis by S.Centrone and Jairo José Da Silva (page 20):
"So, formal logic – Husserl’s mathesis universalis – is in itself a form of knowledge – formal knowledge to give it a name – understood as knowledge of forms, logical forms. Formal knowledge is propaedeutic to material knowledge, which requires the intuitive presentation of the content of knowledge as fulfilling that which is asserted of it. [...] In the particular case of formal mathematics, its task is to investigate all possible forms or structures that domains
of objects, actually existing or not, can possibly display – clearly a variant of
structuralism."
"...can formal knowledge contribute to material knowledge, how? In some aspects, the answer is obvious. Since they hold in general, the laws of the logic of deduction, for example, hold also for any system of materially filled assertions whatsoever. [...] The same is true for formal mathematics; any formal mathematical theory in abstracto instantiates as proper knowledge of any of its materializations (anything that holds for groups in abstracto, for example, holds for any concretely given group). In short, anything that is true for what can possibly exist is per force true of what actually exists. As we can see, for Husserl, mathesis universalis is both in itself a body of (formal) knowledge and an instrument of investigation at the service of the particular sciences, either formal or material."
And see also Mirja Hartimo, Husserl and Mathematics (Cambridge University Press, 2021), Ch.4 Normativity of the Euclidean Ideal, for discussion on Husserl’s Ideas I (1913) and the way it manifests what has been called the “Göttingen idea of preestablished harmony between mathematics and physics.”
Maybe relevant also: Jairo José da Silva, Mathematics and Its Applications: A Transcendental-Idealist Perspective (Springer, 2017).

Thank you. I've been slow to respond because I've been going through the publications, in principle they answer my question, but in a very complex way!

@Ian - you are welcome. Frankly speaking, I'm not a specialist... for what I know, Husserl started his work with Phil of Math, but then the evolution of his thought "diverged" from math and considered only logic in a very broad sense. This, I think, is the reason why we found subsequent devleopment more than original H's sources.


Your first two sections are clear. IMO they correctly describe the
characteristics and the differences of both disciplines. Their
keywords are resp. experience and abstraction.

Hence I do not see what your problem is in the final section. "to
originate from the lifeword" means that mathematics is considered an
abstraction of experience.

That's sometimes correct but it is not
the whole truth. Even "the numbers are free creations of the human mind" (Dedekind).
Many axiomatized mathematical theories are studied without aiming at
any application in the physical word, e.g., Grothendieck's topos theory.



What I mean is that both abstract something from the world, and in their genesis they do not differ, but in what they abstract. In the case of physics, I understand that (for Husserl) there is always a relation to empirical and contingent perception. In mathematics the perceptual element would be irrelevant, right? @Jo Wehler

Aren't they both indistinguishable self similar models of physical reality? They explain physical action and reaction but nothing out of the scope of physics. Its a tall ask for superdeterminism as an explanation of everything including. That that appears on the surface to be out of the bounds of physical determinism. Does every action have an equal and opposite reaction?

@8Mad0Manc8 I don't know if this has any reference in Husserl. For phenomenology, physics is relative insofar is mounted on a prior life-world that it presupposes.

@Ian why get bogged down with what is considered  phenomenon that has no explanation. We incarnate the world physics is not a phenomena our incarnation is.
